# Объсните, что делает этот скрипт?

Tags: bash, shell

```sh
sh -ac 'if test \"$TESTS_ENV\"; then cp environments/env.${TESTS_ENV}.json.template environments/env.json; fi'
```

Единственное, что понимаю, это "если ... тогда скопировать значение из файла `.json.template` в `.json`"

А что такое `sh`, `-ac`, `'if test ...'`, `fi`?

Comment: Если переменная `$TESTS_ENV` не пуста, тогда создать копию файла содержащего в имени значение переменной, задав новое имя `env.json`

Comment: @PotroNik спасибо, а что такое fi в конце ?

Comment: так в  shell обозначается конец блока if

Comment: @Komdosh спасибо

Comment: Конструкция оператора сравнения `if` - начало проверки условия, `then` что делать если условие истинно `else` - что делать если условие ложно(необязательно должно содержаться в конструкции),  `fi` завершение условия проверки, то есть каждый `if` должен завершаться `fi` иначе интерпиритатор вернет ошибку

Comment: @PotroNik большое спасибо, теперь понятно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Команда `sh` запускает новый [shell](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B). Эту команду можно выполнить, находясь в текущем shell, тогда у вас запустится оболочка внутри оболочки. В вашем случае это нужно вероятно для того, чтобы явно указать, что вам нужен интерпретатор `sh`, а не, например, `bash`.

Далее, `-ac` это опции для команды `sh`. Их можно написать по-отдельности `-a -c`.

Опция `-a` согласно [документации](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=sh&category=1&russian=2) отвечает за то, что все объявленные переменные будут автоматически помечаться как [экспортируемые](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=export&category=1&russian=5).

Опция `-c` позволяет запустить следующую за ней команду в кавычках. Например, `sh -c 'echo lalala'` запустит shell внутри текущего shell и распечатает на экран текст lalala.